# Will 1-[2-(chloromethyl)phenyl]propan-2-one, follow a Williamson ether synthesis route or, a Diels-Alder reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I was asked to find the product of potassium ethoxide reaction with 1-[2-(chloromethyl)phenyl]propan-2-one (**1**).

I came up with two different paths, each leading to the same product.

1-[2-(chloromethyl)phenyl]propan-2-one (**1**) on reaction with potassium ethoxide gives a carbanion **2**.

This carbanion **2**, in conjugation with $\ce{C=O}$ gives enolate **3**. This enolate can follow **path 1**, an $\mathrm{S_N}{2}$ reaction (Williamson ether synthesis) to give **4**.

The same carbanion **2** in conjugation with benzene ring gives **6** via allylic rearrangement(**Path 2**).**6** could undergo a possible Diels-Alder reaction giving again **4**.

**My question** is, will the reaction follow **Path 1**, a Williamson ether synthesis route or will it follow **Path 2**, a Diels-Alder reaction.

[image: Suggested Path 1 & 2]

Comment: Path 1 looks the more probable as path 2 breaks the aromaticity of  the system

Comment: @ Waylander , got it.However , is path 2 at all possible , a diels alder route.That would be a different route

Comment: Unrelated to the actual issue of which path is more likely, but I don’t think path 2 can be called a Diels-Alder reaction. It resembles more an 6-pi Electrocyclic Ring Closing reaction.

Comment: Wouldn't you get a different product (2-oxa~ instead of 1-oxa~) via Path 2? The O and a C seem to have changed places in the last step, between 6 and 4